# RealtiveLayout with 2 ImageView and 3 TextView

Tags: android, layout

I would like to have a Llayout like this:
[image: Custom Layout]

So far I have got this Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/game1_background"
     >

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:id="@+id/flag1"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"

         android:id="@+id/team1"
        />
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 



        />

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"

         android:id="@+id/team2"
        />
<ImageView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:id="@+id/flag2"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

But this does not work. Can somebody say why?
thanks

Comment: any specific reason for why you only use a Relative Layout, as I think this can easily be done using a Linear Layout.

Comment: I thought this would be better. But I suppose it would also work with LinearLayout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to get it as close as possible to what you have. I got this:

[image]

This is what you need to do

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
     >
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image1"
        android:text="Text1"
        />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Text2"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/image2"
        android:text="Text3"
        />
<ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Use `android:margin` or `android:padding` to adjust the textbox positions as you like.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/game1_background">
  <ImageView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/flag1"/>
  <TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/team1"/>
  <TextView 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  <TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:id="@+id/team2"/>
  <ImageView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/flag2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

pay attention to the parameter: android:gravity="center_vertical" which will senter all the children vertically.

Answer (score 1):

With `RelativeLayout` you will have to do something like this...

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/flag1"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/team1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/flag1"
    android:text="hello" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/team3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/team1"
    android:text="gth" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/team2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/team3"
    android:text="gth" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/flag2"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/team2"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:text="gth" />
```

Please adjust the dimensions according to your specifications.

RelativeLayout has a set of different properties that can be used to position the Views within the screen, it is easy to learn and is flexible, please refer to [Android documentataion of RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) for more.